# removing duplicates record from a populated field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I ran this query to populate a field with random numbers but it keeps populating with some duplicate records. Any idea how I can remove the duplicates?

```
UPDATE APRFIL
SET ALTATH = CONVERT(int, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10000);
```

Comment: How big is the recordset?

Comment: What reason do you have to believe that when you submit different seeds into the RAND function and convert those to an INT that it should NOT produce random duplicate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate correlative numbers with a random number associated and then
join with the original table on row number to pick the random number:

```
-- create temp table with numbers
    ;WITH r AS (
        SELECT 1 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM r WHERE n+1<=10000
    )
    SELECT n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY NEWID()) random INTO #tempnums FROM r
    OPTION (Maxrecursion 0)

-- update 

    UPDATE x SET ALTATH=t.random
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ALTATH) rown FROM APRFIL) x 
    JOIN #tempnums t ON t.n=x.rown
```

Comment: Is there a query or a way to convert duplicates value in a column to non duplicates.

Comment: This solution won't generate duplicates because every number from 1 to 10000 appears only once and is linked to the original table only once.

Comment: the table already exist so need to create a temp table. Do I need to set all values in the column to NULL first because for some reason I am still getting dupes...

Comment: the table name is APRFIL and column name is ALTATH

Comment: the first sql creates a temptable called #tempnums with 10000 different random numbers and I have now edited the second sql with the name of your tables and columns, so you can just copy-paste.

Comment: If the table has more than 10000 rows you may need to change the first sql .  Where it says "n+1<=10000"  change the 10000 to a number equal or preferably greater,than the amount of random numbers you require.

Comment: you need to start the query with a semi-colon. I've edited it.

Comment: something like this                         ;WITH r AS (
        SELECT 1 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM r WHERE n+1<=10000
    )
    SELECT n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY NEWID()) random INTO #tempnums FROM r
    OPTION (Maxrecursion 0)

Comment: first part ran successfully but having issues with the update part around the status_id                                                                                                         UPDATE APRFIL (altath) SET status_id=t.random
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY whatevercolumn) rown FROM aprfil) x 
    JOIN #tempnums t ON t.n=x.rown

Comment: sorry, I thought I had updated the code. It is now updated  with the name of your table and columns, so please try again.

Comment: you're welcome; please feel free to accept/vote up if you are happy with the answer

Comment: to vote up you can click on the arrow up on top of the number of votes (currently 0). To accept the answer please click on the check mark that looks like a "V" below the number.

Answer (score 1):

Generated Random values might already present in the table. Try this.

```
UPDATE APRFIL
SET    ALTATH = (SELECT ran
                 FROM   (SELECT CONVERT(INT, Rand(Checksum(Newid())) * 10000) ran) a
                 WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM   APRFIL Ap
                                    WHERE  ap.ALTATH = a.ran))
```

**Update:** Better remove the duplicate rows and insert the new records. Use while loop to insert required number of records

```
Insert into APRFIL(ALTATH)
SELECT ran FROM   (SELECT CONVERT(INT, Rand(Checksum(Newid())) * 10000) ran) a
                     WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                        FROM   APRFIL Ap
                                        WHERE  ap.ALTATH = a.ran)
```

Comment: the results are all the same records for the entire field

Comment: @khan16 yeah without a where condition thats how it will update. Add where clause to filter the records to be updated

Comment: @khan16 You need to update one row at a time with this random value

Comment: I need to populate about 30000 rows

Comment: This is a sample output

Comment: 155957
155957
155968
155974
155976
15599
155990
155997
155997
156005
156008
156012
156021
156040

Comment: need to get rid of those duplicate numbers